# MS SQL Server : avoid caching execution plan on a server where I'm not admin

Tags: sql-server

I'm working on some Azure databases where I'm not admin, and I have this issue where, while trying to optimize some queries, at some point my queries are being cached, and I get false "great results".

How can I avoid my queries to be cached?

I would normally run `DBCC FREEPROCCACHE` and `DBCC DROPCLEANBUFFERS`, but since I'm not an admin, I can't do that.

Thanks!

Comment: What do you mean by *'I get false "great results"'*? If you want a query to regenerate it's query plan at the point it runs, you have add `RECOMPILE` to the `OPTION` clause, but that tends to be when you have a catch-all/kitchen sink query. Is that what you have here?

Comment: Execution plans are **always** cached - no way around that.

Comment: Queries are not cached, plans are cached. Use `OPTION RECOMPILE` if you want to avoid caching

Answer (score 1):

> How can I avoid my queries to be cached?

You can always send trivially-different queries.  Any change in the query text, including in a comment will prevent the reuse of a cached plan.

But cached query plans and cached data pages are the normal state of a database.  Cold caches are an abnormal condition.

But stepping back, you can optimize queries in either state.  You should be looking at the query plans and the cost of the queries in CPU and Logical IO, which don't depend on whether the query plan or data pages are already cached.